# Prevent htaccess from redirecting IP's to www

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have this htacceess code to redirect non-www URL's to https://www :

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The website has dedicated IP and when we enter the IP address , Rewrite engine will redirect "107.180.56.244" to "https://www.107.180.56.244" and the site will not load.
What should we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following conditions to stop the redirection for HTTP_HOST ip address :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(\d+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```